# How to append content in file using symfony2 Filesystem?

Tags: symfony

As question is self explanatory. And very common but how can i do with the help of symfony2 components (Filesystem).

I do not see read function in filesystem.

After lot of googles, I could not fine. Please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no function in Symfony2's Filesystem component that appends content to a file. Just use php's built in function:

```
file_put_contents($file, $content, FILE_APPEND);
```

[PHP Documentation on file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

[Symfony2 API for FileSystem Component](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.html)

**EDIT:**

Since Symfony 3.3, it is possible to append content in file:

```
$fs = new Filesystem();
$fs->appendToFile('logs.txt', 'Email sent to user@example.com');
```

[Symfony Filesystem Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html#appendtofile)

Answer (score 2):

Since Symfony 3.3, it is possible to append content in file:

```
$fs = new Filesystem();
$fs->appendToFile('logs.txt', 'Email sent to user@example.com');
```

[Symfony Filesystem Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html#appendtofile)